# Play framework 2 development configuration

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

How I can setup different configuration for development and production mode in Play 2 application?

I've try to use JVM arguments on application start in development mode like this:

```
play "run -Dconfig.resource=dev.conf"
```

or from Play console:

```
run -Dconfig.resource=dev.conf
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 8):

That should work:

```
play -Dconfig.resource=dev.conf "run"
```

Anyway I had some problems with `-Dconfig.resource` so I'm using `-Dconfig.file` instead

```
play -Dconfig.file=/full/path/to/your/project_folder/conf/alt_conf.conf "run"
```

Comment: I am also unable to use `-Dconfig.resource` in dev mode with Play 2.0.3, but `-Dconfig.file` works fine with an absolute path. This JVM system property can also be passed in using the `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable which is "picked up" by the Play python runner script, e.g. `export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dconfig.file=/absolute/path/to/app/conf/dev.conf"` followed by `play run`.

Answer (score 1):

Even better would be to use the standard application.conf file for you development file and use a specific file for your other environments.

Then, using @Biesior's suggestion, you can use in dev :

```
play start
```

And for the other environments, Heroku for example, use the other files :

```
play start -Dconfig.file=conf/application.heroku.conf
```

Comment: Agreed it is better to use custom config file for production environments, but sometimes with existing applications that is not an option.