# Playframework settings depending on environment

Tags: scala, playframework, configuration-files, playframework-2.1

I'm using playframework 2.1-RC2. First of all I've seen [all the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391987/how-do-i-configure-multiple-databases-work-in-play-2-0) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723224/how-to-manage-application-conf-in-several-environments-with-play-2-0) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992834/play-framework-2-development-configuration), so I followed the common instruction of separating application.conf file per environment. So I have application.test.conf and I run tests this way:

```
play -Dconfig.file=./conf/application.test.conf "test"
```

I tried different combinations, like

```
play -Dconfig.file=./conf/application.test.conf ~test
```

or

```
play -Dconfig.file=conf/application.test.conf ~test
```

Still no luck, it just does not get picked, default one (application.conf) is instead.

From the other side, if I do

```
play -Dconfig.file=./conf/application.dev.conf "run"
```

then application picks the right config.

So how can I specify the test configuration file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the most robust way to specifiy this in a cross-platform compatible manner is to include it directly in the Build.scala:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/test.conf",
    ...
)
```

Bonus: configure once and forget ;-)

Comment: man you've made my day. But how comes it that doing the same thing via console does not work?..

Comment: I don't know which OS you run but at least in Windows there is a known, but low priority bug, that play doesn't pass parameters to the JVM correctly (and this is a JVM parameter, not a play parameter). SBT does better ;-)

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but where does the keyword "Test" come from ? Is it possible to do the same thing with environment such as dev/preprod/prod... ? Thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the details, but `Test` is provided by sbt. There are at least `run` and `Compile` which you can also use (guess these are run tasks?), but you certainly can't just make up your own environments.

Comment: shame, looked so promising

Comment: the reason it does not work in the console is that sbt forks the JVM when starting the tests

Comment: This didn't work for me itself, I had also to add `fork in Test := true` (in my build.sbt). Then it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to override method on GlobalSettings / Global named **onLoadConfig** and that enables you to have control where your app will look for your configuration.

So in one of our application I have this setup below for my conf/ folder.

```
 conf/application.conf --> configurations common for all environment
 conf/dev/application.conf --> configurations for development environment
 conf/test/application.conf --> configurations for testing environment
 conf/prod/application.conf --> configurations for production environment
```

With that, you are able to implement inheritance like setup for configuration, you have common and 3 others for specific environment mode.

The code inside your onLoadConfig method should just load main configuration and set correct fallback configuration specific to your environment then return the configuration instance like below:

```
**return new Configuration(baseConfig.withFallback(envConfig));**
```

Try check this [blog post for complete snippet](http://bit.ly/1AiZvX5) of the code.

I hope this helps.