# Play framework 2.1.x and EbeanServer

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.1, ebean

I am struggling with running my first Play! 2.1.x app and I always get this error (this is from running the `test` cases) :

> Test models.TestModel.testCreate failed: The default EbeanServer has not been defined? This is normally set via the ebean.datasource.default property. Otherwise it should be registered programatically via registerServer()

I have read the official manual, many SO questions, and even some blogs and I still can't figure out why I keep on getting this.

**Note:** I specify the `test.conf` file from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14724788/playframework-settings-depending-on-environment), in `Build.scala`.

Here is the content of `test.conf` :

```
include "application.conf"

application.version=${application.major}.${application.minor}.${application.revision}-TEST

db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=PostgreSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"
db.default.user=sa
db.default.password=""

ebean.default="models.*"
ebean.datasource.factory=jndi
ebean.datasource.default=DefaultDS
```

**Note:** the same keys are also specified in `application.conf`, but with the "prod" values.

What am I missing?
Thanks!

#### ** EDIT **

The test case is very straight forward. I am using a base class, copy-pasted as-is from [this blog](http://blog.matthieuguillermin.fr/2012/03/unit-testing-tricks-for-play-2-0-and-ebean/) :

```
public class TestSomeModel extends BaseModelTest {
    @Test
    public void myModelCreate() {
        SomeModel model = new SomeModel();
        model.someStringAttribute = "some value";
    
        assertThat(model.id).isNull();
    
        model.save();  // <--- this is the line that gives the error
        
        assertThat(model.id).isPositive();
    }
}
```

... and if anyone insist on seeing the model class....

```
@Entity
public class SomeModel extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    public String someStringAttribute;
}
```

Comment: Please show the code of your test. Maybe you didn't run the test in a `FakeApplication` ?

Comment: @nico_ekito, code added. Nothing fancy or special about it. It should work, no?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was wrong? I think that I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add @Entity before the model

**@Entity**
public class SomeModel extends Model {

Comment: Thank you and welcome on SO! It was indeed missing. I should've updated the question. This is a hobby project, and I can't work on it as much during the week :)

Answer (score 2):

Try running your test code inside a `fakeApplication()`:

```
import ...
import play.test.Helpers.*;

public class TestSomeModel extends BaseModelTest {
    @Test
    public void myModelCreate() {
        running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                SomeModel model = new SomeModel();
                model.someStringAttribute = "some value";

                assertThat(model.id).isNull();

                model.save();  

                assertThat(model.id).isPositive();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not work either. I had this kind of class in the first place and it *still* didn't work. I researched some more and tried the model base class (see my question's comment) to remove some boiler plate code. And I know the code is executed because I had other issues that I managed to fix. In short, the problem does not seem to be the `fakeApplication()`, but rather that the EbeanServer is not setup, for some reason.

Comment: Just to make sure, have you properly added the `javaEbean` dependency in your `Build.scala` file ?

Comment: I am using Eclipse and I have generated the project and eclipse project directly from the Play! console, yes. So, apart from some other config that I am not aware of, `javaEbean` is declared in `val appDependencies = Seq(...)`.

Comment: Are you running your tests from Eclipse or from the Play console ?

Comment: Try to instanciate the EbeanServer manually: `Ebean.getServer("default")`

Comment: Instanciating the EbeanServer manually, now I get this : `Test models.TestSomeModel failed: DataSource user is null?`

Comment: Just for testing, remove or comment the `db.default.jndiName` property.

Comment: same thing.... I'm clueless. Play 1.2 was so easy to use... and Play 2.x seriously lack documentation....

Comment: No more clue... Maybe try starting from the "computer-database" project in the "samples" directory of the Play distrib ?